# What is a nonarithmetic distribution? can give an example?

Tags: probability-distributions, random-variables, renewal-processes

Please, I need some help understanding what is a non-arithmetic distribution.

I found this definition for Arithmetic Distribution [here](https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Arithmetic_distribution):

A discrete probability distribution concentrated on a set of points of the form $\pm nh$, where $h>0$ and $n=1,2,...$.

But don't really understand it.

To be clear, is a Bernoulli distribution non-arithmetic? It seems it is not.

Thanks!

Comment: Seems like a fairly situational definition.  Standard Bernoulli is certainly an example, or at least it could be made to be. Any continuous distribution would be non-arithmetic, in this sense.  As would some unusual thing like $P\left( \frac mn\right)=C\frac 1{n^4}$ for whatever constant makes the total probability $1$.  (take $0≤m<n$ so we get a convergent sum).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I just editted my comment. The definition I found is for Arithmetic, not for non-arithmetic. But I guess I does apply as the opposite. ?

Comment: I assumed the definition you gave was for "arithmetic".  As in "supported on an arithmetic progression."

Comment: Just to clarify:  any finite set of real numbers can be viewed as part of an arithmetic progression,.  My example gave an infinite set which is clearly not part of an arithmetic progression, which can nonetheless support a probability distribution.

Comment: @lulu - if $0 \lt m \lt n$, and $m$ and $n$ are coprime then your $C=\frac{\zeta(4)}{\zeta(3) - \zeta(4) }$

Comment: @Henry Thanks!  $\quad $

Comment: Thanks for the replies, I'm really new in this. So this is related to the support of the random variable right? To the actual values it can take?

Comment: @lulu: how would you get for example $1,2,\pi$ into an arithmetic progression?

Comment: @Henry Good point.  So there are finite "non-arithmetic" distributions after all.

Comment: @Henry arithmetic mean ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your quoted definition is apparently for an *arithmetic distribution* and I would be surprised if the value $0$ was not allowed.

In effect, given a random variable $X$, if there is any positive real number $h$ such that $Y=\frac1h X$ is a random variable which can only take integer values, then $X$ has an *arithmetic distribution*.

If there is no such $h$ then $X$ has a *non-arithmetic distribution*.  Examples include

- any continuous distribution
- $P(X=\frac 1n) = \frac6{\pi^2 n^2}$ for positive integer $n$

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  So to say, I have the following uniform distribution for the values $X$ can take in the set $\{1,2,3,4 \}$ each with $p=1/4$. Is this non-arithmetic?

Comment: No - it is very arithmetic (you can take $h=1$) as all the possible values of $X$ are integers

Comment: Ohh. Thank you @Henry.. I finally see it.  So basically arithmetic is having a support for the random variable that can be say, modeled, as some arithmetic progression or series. And that is why any continuous distribution is non-arithmetic, since its support has infinite values.